# python/Scipy Interpolation of 3D scattered data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I want to implement a interpolation of a 3D scattered data using python.

Such as,

z[0,0] = 1, z[0,4] =2, z[2,2]=4, z[4,0]=3, z[4,4]= 2 (X like structured 2D vectors with z value)

and interpolate these data so that
I can derive a z value between this (x,y) coordinate like z[1,2], z[2,3], z[1,1], ..., etc.

I coded like below using scipy and numpy but I guess using numpy.empty((5,5)) is not suitable for my purpose because numpy.empty() add values which is irrelevant. And I want to interpolate only with 5 points.

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,4,5)
y = np.linspace(0,4,5)
xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = np.empty((5,5)) # I think this is wrong
z[0,0] = 1, z[0,4] =2, z[2,2]=4, z[4,0]=3, z[4,4]= 2 

f = interpolate.interp2d(x,y,z,kind='linear')

xt = np.linspace(0,4,10)
yt = np.linspace(0,4,10)
xxt, yyt = np.meshgrid(xt,yt)
ct = f(xt,yt)
```

my expected output is values with 2D 5x5 (or larger area such as 7x7, 9x9, etc) arrays which is the result of interpolation of 5 constant points.
Could you help me?

Comment: Can you include what your expected output (`ct`?) should look like.

Comment: This is very general question, whose answer depends on many factors, mainly the purpose of interpolation, where the secondary coordinates are (e.g. inside convex hull or not). Once you know the general method in mathematical words, coding in python is easy. E.g. you can do Delaunay triangulation, find the correct triangle for given x,y and interpolate on it. Or you can do some wighted average of "close" points using a kernel function. Or...... all in all, SO is IMO not a good place for this question..

Comment: @JanStránský Thank you very much. I got enlightenment that this is a mathematical general problem. Anyway, I wanted to derive z values by refering to nearest three (x,y) points I think Delaunay triangulation will be a useful reference.

Comment: @drekbour I added specific explanation thanks.